# Cannot import name Label from pandas._typing

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I faced this issue while was trying to export a dataframe to a csv file.
I cannot find any similar issue online on this issue. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I am using pandas 1.3 with python 3.7.1.

```py
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

/tmp/ipykernel_30888/2657956500.py in image_viewer(chunk_num, img_dir, chunk_size, zoom)
     89     df = df[~df.img_name.duplicated(keep='last')]
     90 
---> 91     df.to_csv(output_name, index=False)
     92 
     93     return df

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/labelvalidation-cagv8R9l/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal, errors, storage_options)
   3480             self._check_setitem_copy(stacklevel=5, t="referent")
   3481 
-> 3482         if clear:
   3483             self._clear_item_cache()
   3484 

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/labelvalidation-cagv8R9l/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, encoding, sep, columns, index_label, mode, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, errors, storage_options)
   1076             quotechar=quotechar,
   1077             date_format=date_format,
-> 1078             doublequote=doublequote,
   1079             escapechar=escapechar,
   1080             storage_options=storage_options,

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/labelvalidation-cagv8R9l/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py in <module>
     10 
     11 from pandas._libs import writers as libwriters
---> 12 from pandas._typing import (
     13     CompressionOptions,
     14     FilePathOrBuffer,

ImportError: cannot import name 'Label' from 'pandas._typing'
```

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded to pandas 0.20.3 and the issue is now gone!